# sqlanydb windows could not load dbcapi

Tags: python, sqlanywhere, sqlanydb

I am trying to connect to a SQL Anywhere database via python. I have created the DSN and I can use command prompt to connect to the database using `dbisql - c "DNS=myDSN"`. When I try to connect through python using `con = sqlanydb.connect(DSN= "myDSN")` 
I get

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    con = sqlanydb.connect(DSN= "RPS Integration")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 522, in connect
    return Connection(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 538, in __init__
    parent = Connection.cls_parent = Root("PYTHON")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 464, in __init__
    'libdbcapi_r.dylib')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 456, in load_library
    raise InterfaceError("Could not load dbcapi.  Tried: " + ','.join(map(str, names)))
InterfaceError: (u'Could not load dbcapi.  Tried: None,dbcapi.dll,libdbcapi_r.so,libdbcapi_r.dylib', 0)`
```

Comment: Did you try this documentation of Sybase ?http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01776.1600/doc/html/san1357754966211.html

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I am having a similar problem.

Comment: I was sort of able to resolve the problem, so I posted an answer. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the problem. I was never able to use the sqlanydb.connect. I ended up using pyodbc. So my final connection string was `con = pydobc.connect(dsn="myDSN")`. I think that sqlanydb is only fully functional with sqlanydb 17 and I was using a previous version.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how Sybase is locally installed, it could also be that the Python module really cannot find the (correct) library when looking up `dbcapi.dll` in your `PATH`. A quick fix for that is to create a new `SQLANY_API_DLL` environment variable ([that's the initial `None` in the names the error message says it tried using](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlanydb/blob/952183ab0504d14b3e32f2f5afb674514492deee/sqlanydb.py#L464-L466); it takes priority over all the others) containing the correct path, usually something like `%SQLANY16%\Bin64\dbcapi.dll` depending on what version you have installed (Sybase usually creates an environment variable pointing to its installation folder on a per version basis).

Answer (score 0):

One way to encounter the backtrace shown by the OP is running 64-bit Python interpreter, which is unable to load the 32-bit dbcapi.dll.  Try launching with "py -X-32" to force a 32-bit engine, or reinstall using a 32-bit python engine.

Unfortunately sqlanydb's code that tries to be smart about finding dbcapi also ends up swallowing the exceptions thrown during loading.  The sqlanydb author probably assumed that failure to load implies file not found, which isn't always the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was stoked in this same problem, both windows `system32` and `64`.

I'm using `Python 3.9` and I found that since `Python 3.8` the `cdll.LoadLibrary` function does no longer search `PATH` to find library files.

To fix this, I created the enviroment variable `SQLANY_API_DLL` pointing to the route of `sqlanywhere installation`, in my case version 17, bin32 or bin64 depending on your system.